# Error initializing classpath: Could not find org.grails.plugins:jasper:1.11.0

Tags: grails

I am getting

> Error initializing classpath: Could not find org.grails.plugins:jasper:1.11.0.

while I was running `grails install-plugin jasper`

```
https://grails.org/plugin/jasper?skipRedirect=true
```

According to above link I addded 
dependencies

```
{compile "org.grails.plugins:jasper:1.11.0" }
```

We are not using Maven

So I ran `grails install-plugin jasper`. I am getting the follwing error

> Error Error initializing classpath: Could not find org.grails.plugins:jasper:1.11.0.

Searched in the following locations:

```
file:/C:/Users/namasivayams/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/jasper/1.11.0/jasper-1.11.0.pom
file:/C:/Users/namasivayams/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/jasper/1.11.0/jasper-1.11.0.jar   
https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/jasper/1.11.0/jasper-1.11.0.jar
```

I try to download `jasper-1.11.0.jar`. I could not find any site to download.
How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following repository to build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins" }
    // other repositories
}
```