# Grails Jasper plugin - Error Command not found install-plugin - running grails install-plugin jasper - Grails 3.1.9

Tags: grails

i asked the question regarding an error which descriped in the following link.
[Error initializing classpath: Could not find org.grails.plugins:jasper:1.11.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43642091/error-initializing-classpath-could-not-find-org-grails-pluginsjasper1-11-0)

as the link suggested i added 
maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins" }

after that i was running "grails install-plugin jasper" command.
i am getting the following error.
"Error Command not found install-plugin
Did you mean: install or list-plugins or plugin-info?
"

not sure why i am getting. I am using Grails 3.1.6 and groovy2.4

I am following the instruction from this url to install.
https://grails.org/plugin/jasper?skipRedirect=true

Answer (score 0):

`install-plugin` is deprecated in Grails 3

Grails will add the plugin for you so long as specify it in the `dependencies` section of build.gradle

Comment: did this help you?